# Producto.ID IN Error.MULTIDELETE

Tags: mysql

Quiero borrar el registro de porductoId donde la cantidad es null, pero me sale un error.

```
delete productoId
from producto p
left join ventas v on p.ProductoId=v.ProductoId
WHERE v.cantidad is null
```

Lo que quiero borrar es el productoId:

```
select p.productoId, v.cantidad
from producto p
left join ventas v on p.ProductoId=v.ProductoId
WHERE v.cantidad is null
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que no estas indicando de que tabla quieres borrar.

#### Solución:

Si lo que quieres es borrar los productos entonces debes indicar el alias de la tabla. En tu caso es `p`

#### Ejemplo:

```
DELETE p
FROM producto p
LEFT JOIN ventas v ON p.ProductoId = v.ProductoId
WHERE v.cantidad IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66ee00/1/0)</kbd>

---

### Actualización:

> Me sale este error cuando lo hago asi: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

Aparentemente tu `MySQL` tiene activo [`actualizaciones seguras`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates).

Para desactivarlo, **antes** de realizar la consulta, tienes que ejecutar:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Comment: Me sale este error cuando lo hago asi: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

Comment: @mel Seguramente lo siguiente te servirá: [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench) El error significa que no puedes actualizar o eliminar registros sin especificar una clave en la cláusula where.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, ya me funciono!

Answer (score 0):

Fijate como tenes configurada la relación en cuanto a las restricciones (que comportamiento toma al borrar o modificar una tabla relacionada con otra)

```
Alter table .... ....  ON DELETE X ON UPDATE X;
```

Donde x es: RESTRICT no te deja borrar registros si esta asociada a otra tabla.
SET NUll borra el registro de la tabla y setea a null la tabla asociada.
CASCADE borra el registro de la tabla y todos los asociados.
NO ACTION borra el registro de la tabla y la otra tabla ni se entera.